# Save all values of a variable (in a loop) in another variable in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list

I have a code that I inform a folder, where it has `n` images that the code should return me the relative frequency histogram.

From there I have a function call:

```
for image in total_images:
    histogram(image)
```

Where `image` is the current image that the code is working on and `total_images` is the total of images (`n`) it has in the previously informed folder.

And from there I call the `histogram()` function, sending as a parameter the current image that the code is working.

My `histogram()` function has the purpose of returning the histogram of the relative frequency of each image (`rel_freq`).

Although the returned values ​​are correct, `rel_freq` should be a array 1x256 positions ranging from 0 to 255.

How can I transform the `rel_freq` variable into a 1x256 array? And each value stored in its corresponding position?

When I do `len *rel_freq)` it returns me 256, that's when I realized that it is not in the format I need...

Again, although the returned data is correct...

After that, I need to create an array `store_all = len(total_images)x256` to save all `rel_freq`...

I need to save all `rel_freq` in an array to later save it and to an external file, such as .txt.

I'm thinking of creating another function to do this...

Something like that, but I do not know how to do it correctly, but I believe you will understand the logic...

```
def store_all_histograms(total_images):
    n = len(total_images)

    store_all = [n][256]

    for i in range(0,n):
        store_all[i] = rel_freq
```

I know the function `store_all_histograms()` is wrong, I just wrote it here to show more or less the way I'm thinking of doing... but again, I do not know how to do it properly... At this point, the error I get is:

```
    store_all = [n][256]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

After all, I need the `store_all` variable to save all relative frequency histograms for example like this:

```
position:     0   ...  256 
store_all = [
            [..., ..., ...],
            [..., ..., ...],
            .
            .
            .
            n
            ]
```

Now follow this block of code:

```
def histogram(path):
    global rel_freq

    #Part of the code that is not relevant to the question...

    rel_freq = [(float(item) / total_size) * 100 if item else 0 for item in abs_freq]

def store_all_histograms(total_images):
    n = len(total_images)

    store_all = [n][256]

    for i in range(0,n):
        store_all[i] = rel_freq

#Part of the code that is not relevant to the question...

# Call the functions
for fn in total_images:
    histogram(fn)

    store_all_histograms(total_images)
```

I hope I have managed to be clear with the question.

Thanks in advance, if you need any additional information, you can ask me...

Comment: "When I do len (rel_freq) it returns me 256, that's when I realized that it is not in the format I need..." what do you expect from a 1x256 array? `len` is a python builtin.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. A longer question is not necessarily better than a brief one. I have a hard time understanding what is the important part of your question is. Here's a guide to writing great questions: [ask]

Comment: @roganjosh I need this because I will later put the value of the histograms into the Multilayer Perceptron and see if it is able to classify my images.

Comment: @HåkenLid Thanks and sorry.

Comment: That's fine. I perhaps wasn't clear; the `len` of a 1x256 array will just show `256` so even if it's a `numpy` array, `len` will look at it like a (nested if necessary, which it's not here) list. That's not an indication that anything went wrong. As @HåkenLid stated, your question is quite long and that was the first issue I picked up on.

Comment: No need to be sorry. :) Hope you get a useful answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the result, don't use a global variable:

```
def histogram(path):
    return [(float(item) / total_size) * 100 if item else 0 for item in abs_freq]
```

Create an empty list:

```
store_all = []
```

and append your results:

```
for fn in total_images:
    store_all.append(histogram(fn))
```

Alternatively, use a list comprehension:

```
store_all = [histogram(fn) for fn in total_images]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0,n):
    store_all[i+1] = rel_freq
```

Try this perhaps?  I'm a bit confused on the question though if I'm honest.  Are you trying to shift the way you call the array with all the items by 1 so that instead of calling position 1 by list[0] you call it via list[1]?

So you want it to act like this?

```
>>list = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>list[1]
0
```

Comment: `>>list = [[0,0,0,0,...,0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1,...,1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2,...,2,2,2,2]]`
`>>list[3]`
`>>[2,2,2,2,...,2,2,2,2]`

This is how I need it...